# Boolean Not working with Guideway

Tags: modifiers

[Link to file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvVaPJeayOq7VebFMtvUG8oKtfiLFhx1/view?usp=sharing)

A I had a cube that cuts through the shape (track), but I want the track to through a cube which is not happening. Can someone please explain why the inverse is not happening. I deleted the cube in the file.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to explain exactly what you're expecting to happen. I don't see a cube in your scene and there isn't a boolean modifier on any of the objects in your Blend file. To add to that the Scale and Rotation haven't been applied to any of the objects in Object mode and the face orientation is fllipped on all of them.

Comment: Hi, Stanley R, welcome.. I'm sorry, but the phrasing of this post, and the attached file, leave us absolutely clueless as to what you want to achieve. Without an edit, the question is vulnerable to getting wiped for lack of clarity.

Comment: The track normals are inverted...

Comment: Thank you, So how do I invert the normals?